# Run script at boot after MySQL started

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, boot

I want to start Seafile (cloud-server which needs MySQL) at the boot of my Raspberry Pi. My Problem is, that the Seafile starts befor mysql and caused many errors, because seafile needs mysql.
I took the recommended script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/seafile

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          seafile
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network mysql
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Script to start/stop/restart seafile
# Description:       Simple script to start, stop or restart seafile for the cloud
### END INIT INFO

# Change the value of "user" to your linux user name
user=chromo

# Change the value of "script_path" to your path of seafile installation
seafile_dir=/home/chromo/cloud
script_path=${seafile_dir}/seafile-server-latest
seafile_init_log=${seafile_dir}/logs/seafile.init.log
seahub_init_log=${seafile_dir}/logs/seahub.init.log

# Change the value of fastcgi to true if fastcgi is to be used
fastcgi=true
# Set the port of fastcgi, default is 8000. Change it if you need different.
fastcgi_port=8000

case "$1" in
    start)
            sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seafile.sh start >> ${seafile_init_log}
if [  $fastcgi = true ];
            then
                    sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seahub.sh start-fastcgi ${fastcgi_port} >> ${seahub_init_log}
            else
                    sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seahub.sh start >> ${seahub_init_log}
            fi
    ;;
    restart)
            sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seafile.sh restart >> ${seafile_init_log}
            if [  $fastcgi = true ];
            then
                    sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seahub.sh restart-fastcgi ${fastcgi_port} >> ${seahub_init_log}
            else
                    sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seahub.sh restart >> ${seahub_init_log}
            fi
    ;;
stop)
            sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seafile.sh $1 >> ${seafile_init_log}
            sudo -u ${user} ${script_path}/seahub.sh $1 >> ${seahub_init_log}
    ;;
    *)
            echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/seafile {start|stop|restart}"
            exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -2):

The best thing would be to set priority for starting these services in `/etc/rc[runlevel].d` file.

In your case, the first thing to check would be the runlevel to which you have boot into. You can check this using the command "`runlevel`". You can also check

Say, you have been booted in to runlevel 3. You can rename the current seafile file in directory "`/etc/rc3.d`".

For eg:

If the two files are

```
/etc/rc3.d/20seafile
/etc/rc3.d/50mysql
```

Rename the file as `70seafile` or anything higher than 50.

This should fix the issue you are facing now.

Another workaround will be removing the seafile link to /etc/init.d directory and put a line saying

```
/etc/init.d/seafile start
```

inside the file `/etc/rc.local`

Please check this and let me know if it has fixed the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not work for me. ´runlevel´ showed me "n 2", so my system is running at 2, then I set the number of seafile higher than MySQL, but it does not work. The second solution does not work too, because rc.local seems to be executed, only when I log in per ssh.

Comment: ok, I got it work now! I work with Debian an in this distribution the number (eg S20 and S50) are ignored. I added at the LSB-Infos at Required-Start: mysql and executed the command: sudo insserv -d.

Comment: @Chromo.. Great!! Somehow I was thinking only about Centos servers.